# Python Dictionary from some csv files

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dictionary

I have a serie of tables, each table represent a date, and each column of the table represent a variable:

Table 1 for date 2000-11-28

```
 LYR  VAR1  VAR2  VAR3  VAR4 
  1    4.4   3.1   2.2   1.8  
  2    6.3   6.5   2.5   2.7  
  3    8.7   2.4   4.7   7.8
```

and table 2 for date 2000-11-29

```
 LYR  VAR1  VAR2  VAR3  VAR4 
  1    2.4   6.3   7.2   2.4  
  2    5.1   7.6   4.3   5.2  
  3    7.6   9.8   2.6   0.1
```

I have many tables like this.

I try to create a dictionary from these tables to plot a time series.

I read each one using pandas DataFrame:

```
>> import pandas as pd
>>
>> tb1 = pd.read_csv('data_20001128',sep='\s+')
>> t1  = tb1.to_dict('series')

>> tb2 = pd.read_csv('data_20001129',sep='\s+')
>> t2  = tb2.to_dict('series')
```

How can I merge t1 and t2 to have a unique table in each dictionary, like this:

```
>> tables['VAR1'] 
   2000-11-28 2000-11-29
0         4.4        2.4
1         6.3        5.1
2         8.7        7.6
```

at the end of the process I need plot a graphic that each row will be a line. I will do this using the matplotlib.

thanks

Comment: You probably want to stack them vertically, and have a column for the date.  Use the date column to color code your lines in the graph.

Answer (score 0):

Do you really need dictionary? Or a MultiIndex dataframe works for you:

```
tables = (pd.concat([tb1,tb2], keys=['2000-11-28', '2000-11-29']).unstack(level=0))

tables['VAR1']
```

Output:

```
   2000-11-28  2000-11-29
0         4.4         2.4
1         6.3         5.1
2         8.7         7.6
```

Comment: Thanks, I think that this solution is fine for me! I have a lot of tables, for 6 months, and I need plot a time series. So I think that this is a good solution.